# Tree Builder issue with unicode text

Tags: perl, unicode, html-treebuilder

I am using `HTML::TreeBuilder` to extract contents of a url by using `tree->lookdown` and then extracting text part from the string returned in lookdown method. My problem here is when I read that text and write it into a file its showing as junk. I am not able to make a progress regarding this.

My Sample Code:

```
use HTML::TreeBuilder;
use HTML::Element;

use utf8;

$url = $ARGV[0];
$page = `wget -qO -  "$url"| tee data.txt`;
#print "iam $page\n";
my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new(  );
$tree->parse_file('data.txt');

my @story = $tree->look_down(
    _tag  => 'div',
    class => 'storydescription'
);

my @title = $tree->look_down(
    _tag  => 'title'
);

open(OUT,">","story.txt") or die"Cannot open story.txt:$!\n";
binmode(OUT,":utf8");

foreach my $story(@story) {
    print OUT $story->as_text;
}
close(OUT);
```

I have tried binmode for the output file handle but it was of no use and the text other than Unicode such as ascii characters prints properly into file.

Comment: Rather than shell out just to use `wget`, you should do it in Perl: `use LWP::Simple qw/ getstore /` and then `getstore($url, 'data.txt')` will achieve the same result. You can also write `HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_file('data.txt')` to avoid the two-step create and parse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's documented in [HTML::TreeBuilder](http://p3rl.org/HTML::TreeBuilder):

> When you pass a filename to `parse_file`, `HTML::Parser` opens it in
>   binary mode, which means it's interpreted as Latin-1 (ISO-8859-1). If
>   the file is in another encoding, like UTF-8 or UTF-16, this will not
>   do the right thing.
>
> One solution is to open the file yourself using the proper `:encoding`
>   layer, and pass the filehandle to `parse_file`. You can automate this
>   process by using "html_file" in `IO::HTML`, which will use the HTML5
>   encoding sniffing algorithm to automatically determine the proper
>   `:encoding` layer and apply it.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Choroba. The solution worked fine and I didnt know the issue is documented.